# Subsequent calls to dynamic finders in grails results in groovy.lang.MissingMethodException

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two integration tests.  I'm trying to use a dynamic finder in both on a class called RoutingLane.  The second test fails with the MissingMethodException.

```
Failure:  testMockRouteLane2(compliance.processor.services.CalculationServiceTests)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: RoutingLane.methodMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

The mock functions are:

```
void testMockRouteLane() {
    def routingLaneMock = RoutingLane.findAllByMot('TL')
    assert routingLaneMock != null
    assert routingLaneMock.size() >= 1
}

void testMockRouteLane2() {
    def routingLaneMock = RoutingLane.findAllByMot('TL')
    assert routingLaneMock != null
    assert routingLaneMock.size() >= 1
}
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: How does the domain class `RoutingLane` look like?

Comment: I put a snippet out on pastebin, http://pastebin.com/35ajbFkW
I changed some of the package full names for privacy reasons.

Comment: Are you using `buildTestDomain()` to populate the domain obj in itg test?

Comment: No I'm populating the in-memory H2 database in the dataSource configuration in the test environment closure.

  dataSource_testdatasource {
   dbCreate = "update"
   url = "jdbc:h2:mem:btfdw;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;INIT=runscript from 'sample_bootstrap_data.sql'"
   logSql = true
  }

Comment: How about a `setUp()`/`@Before`?

Comment: I'm not using a setUp() / @Before... do I need to?  I just think it's strange that the second test fails but the first one succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to answer my own question, since I have discovered the issue, thanks to reading another thread.

[Grails integration tests with multiple services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016659/grails-integration-tests-with-multiple-services)

It was due to me converting this to an integration test from a unit test, and not removing the `@TestFor` annotation for the service class name.

Hopefully this helps anyone else that encounters the issue.